# How to decrypt Chrome saved password from "Login Data" file

Tags: chrome, decryption

Is there a way to decrypt passwords from Chrome Login Data file?

My goal is learning about the backend process of this decryption, so I don't want to use any pre-built applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome uses the operating system's API to encrypt passwords. In windows the called function is [CryptProtectData](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

There are several tools for decrypting Chrome passwords, but generally they involve being logged in as the user who saved them. If instead you want to proceed from scratch, I suggest you study the Microsoft documentation on the encryption function.